# Buzztouch geo location not working compiled in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, geolocation, xcode6

I upgraded to xcode 6, compiled a new app, discovered that the geo location is not working, and am searching for a work around.

There is no option in the phone's settings for the newly compiled app to choose a privacy/location services option "Never" or "always.

The older apps compiled in xcode5 still have this option.

UPDATE
Problem solved. Compiled in BT 3.0
- Added this code in BT_screen_customURL.m under the //appDelegate comment (line 64)

```
if ([appDelegate.rootLocationMonitor.locationManager     respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)])
[appDelegate.rootLocationMonitor.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
```

- Added these as string messages to info.plist
  NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription
  NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription

Additonal informaton:  https://www.buzztouch.com/forum/thread.php?tid=DA308929DBC29D1DB83B7A8&currentPage=1

Also, the link provided by Alberto below was helpful.

Comment: please, google a bit

Answer (score 2):

Your app is write in Objective C?

add the following lines:

kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways <- For background battery-killers.
kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse <- For sensible apps.

in your plist

For more information: http://www.splinter.com.au/2014/09/14/ios8-corelocation/

Best,
Alberto